# Using class to solve the puzzle of light but having trouble of flipping. (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is the task:

> I have a board of Lights, numbered 0,1,2,...,1023.
>   Each Light can be either on or off. All Lights are initially off.
>
> Step 1:
>
> I flip all of the Lights starting at 0.
>   At this point, all of the Lights are on.
>
> Step 2: I flip every second Light, starting at 0.
>   At this point, Lights 0,2,4,6,8,... are off.
>   Lights 1,3,5,7,9,... are still on.
>
> Step 3: I flip every third Light, starting at 0.
>   So I flip Lights 0,3,6,9,12,...
>   that is, if a Light is on, I flip it to off.
>   If a Light is off, I flip it on.
>
> ...
>
> Step 1023:
>   I flip every 1023'rd Light, starting at 0.
>   So I flip 0 and 1023.
>
> Question: At this point, which Lights are on and which are off?

And here is my code:

```
class Light:

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 'OFF'

    def turn_on(self):
        self.state = 'ON'

    def turn_off(self):
        self.state = 'OFF'

    def flip(self):
        if self.state == 'OFF':
            self.state = 'ON'
        else:
            self.state = 'OFF'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.state)


class LightBoard:

    def __init__(self, num_lights):
        self.light = [Light()] * num_lights

    def step(self,i):
        for element in self.light:
            if self.light.index(element) % i == 0:
                self.light[self.light.index(element)] = self.light[self.light.index(element)].flip()

    def all_steps(self):
        i = 0
        while i != len(self.light):
            self.light = self.light.step(self.light, i)
            i += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.light)
```

I used python visualizer and found that the all_steps in LightBoard does not work.

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'step'

I am lost in correcting it.
Please help correcting/ giving comments on my code. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem, but your question helped me in finding a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is in

```
    self.light = [Light()] * num_lights
```

This needs to be changed to

```
    self.light = [Light() for _ in range(num_lights)]
```

Otherwise, `self.light` consists of references to the same `Light` object.

There are other problems, including:

1. You need two levels of loops and not just one.
2. The following has several errors in it: `self.light = self.light.step(self.light, i)`. One problem is that you're calling `step` on `self.light`, which is a list.

P.S. Do you have to write a program for this? It's one of those problems that can be fairly easily solved using pen and paper.